# Are these two equivalent

Tags: resistors, transmission-line

Are these two equivalent? Z is characteristic impedance of the transmission line and theta is electrical length of it.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your schematics. The first one has two components, the second one has only one component and some text in the middle. What are the values of the components supposed to be?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson "some text in the middle" is a common (and somewhat annoyingly unclear) notation for a transmission line.

Answer (score 1):

No. As you can see, the top one has only one terminal, and the bottom one has two terminals; thus they cannot be equivalent as any two equivalent subcircuits must have the same number of terminals.

Comment: but if i am not mistaken the one which is above is just one way (simpler) of representing transmission line and bottom one is another way. Can we say that both of them represent: transmission line in series with the resistor?

Comment: No, because one has a grounded end and the other doesn't.

Comment: On top of that you still can't, because the high-frequency performance of a transmission line is far more complicated than a single series element. How good an approximation it is to use a single series element depends on how long your transmission line is relative to the wavelength of the signal of interest.

Comment: yes understood, thank you very much. How can we calculate the input impedance of the one above, where resistor is shorted?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. That sounds like a topic for a different question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're equivalent.

In the top diagram, the return path is implied by the ground symbol, while in the bottom diagram, it is explicit.

They both represent the same physical system.

Comment: They represent the same system if a rectangle with some notation under it means "a hunk of transmission line referenced to ground" and if one of the terminals on the left side of the bottom diagram were grounded.  I (initially) read the top one as an impedance in series with a resistor -- I'm not sure if that's what it would mean in RF scratch-pad schematic language, though.

Comment: @TimWescott: The OP explicitly stated that \$Z, \theta\$ represents a transmission line in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are the same if your parallel lines in the lower once represent and transmission line with the same effect as the symbolic mode above it with a lumped characteristic impedance with phase at some f.

But if you expected everyone to. Assume your lower diagram was a ‘logic” or symbolic schematic then you are confusing physical parallel tracks with a dielectric constant between them or just showing a mathematical model of two lines with Z(f) then they are equivalent.  Schematics are usually logical like the 1st and not physical with a math function in shunt with a load.

A series transmission line also has a shunt input characteristic impedance and a transfer function at some f such that the transmission line can convert or “transform”  the load to a different equivalent input impedance.

Somewhat but not same as a Norton or Thevenin equivalent cct. As it is frequency sensitive.

The 1st shows a 0V Gnd reference while the second is a floating differential input which is never used for transmission lines but may be grounded on the lower side AT SOURCE.

So technically it could be argued that the 2nd diagram is ambiguous as there is no 0V reference and only arrows showing 2 lines with opposite current flow. So logically the same but bad way of representing the circuit without a ground to define the 0V reference to a transmission line. So this is only done in  academia to show you the “theoretical” equivalent circuit.